# VSCode: "${userHome} not working when used in "powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code

when I use [VS Code variable](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference) ${userHome} like this, in the following setting :

```
"powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths": {
        "V7_Core": "${userHome}/apps/PowerShell/pwsh.exe"
},
```

VsCode PowerShell extension use Windows Powershell.
I have to use an absolute path to have it load pwsh instead

Comment: Does `~` or `${env:USERPROFILE}` work in place of `${userHome}`?

Comment: variables work in `tasks.json` and `launch.json`, where do you use this.

Comment: @rioV8

Thanks for pointing this out, I didn't notice that restriction of the use of variables!

BTW  "powershell.powerShellAdditionalExePaths its in "settings.json"

Comment: for my extensions I allow variables in the settings or templates but I have to implement it in each extension

Comment: `${env:USERPROFILE}` worked for me but indeed `${userHome]` was empty, on Windows 11